# How can I test a HOC on jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I wrote a HOC, in order to inject reducers dinamically on my project, which worked well. But I'm having a hard time to test this on jest. My doubt is how to test which this Extended class return, inside withReducer function, and how to test if contextType function (store.injectReducer) was called with the correct params.

My withReducer.js

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-deprecated */
import React from 'react';
import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';

export const withReducer = (key, reducer) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Extended extends React.Component {
    static WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;

    componentWillMount() {
      const { store } = this.context;

      store.injectReducer(key, reducer);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  Extended.contextType = ReactReduxContext;

  return Extended;
};

export default withReducer;
```

My test Function

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { identity } from 'lodash';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { withReducer } from '../withReducer';
import initializeStore from '../initializeStore';

const Component = jest.fn();

let store;
let ComponentWithReducer;
const reducer = identity;

beforeEach(() => {
  store = initializeStore();
  ComponentWithReducer = withReducer('test', reducer)(Component);
});

describe('withReducer', () => {
  it('should propagate props', () => {
    const props = { testProp: 'test' };
    const renderedComponent = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ComponentWithReducer {...props} />
      </Provider>, {
        context: { store },
      },
    );

    expect(renderedComponent.dive().props()).toEqual(props); // works
    // how test render() return here
    // how to test that store.injectReducer(key, reducer) was called here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `injectReducer` function in store:

```
const props = { testProp: 'test' };

const mockFn = jest.fn();

const renderedComponent = shallow(
  <Provider store={{ injectReducer: mockFn }}>
    <ComponentWithReducer {...props} />
  </Provider>, {
    context: { store },
  },
);

expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test', reducer);
```

Comment: I tried this, but jest says function was never called... If I at least could call componentWillMount() function, but I don't know how to access this on this case.

Comment: What version of react are you using? You might need to use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: I'm using react 16.12.0. About `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`, I think it's the same behavior of using deprecrated componentWillMount function, am I right? Anyway, I'll change this and test it again.

Comment: Yes, both have the same behavior. But react deprecated the use of `componentWillMount` 16.9.0 onwards. Let me know if the test still doesn't work.

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately this test case still fail. We expect this function to be calling once, but it didn't call at all.

Comment: What version of enzyme are you using? Also, how about you try using mount instead of shallow?